# Executing java program and writing files inside the files structure of Bazel

Tags: bazel-java

I’m using a “ctx.action.run”  command to execute a java.jar program.
The java program uses as imputs “bazel-bin/src/files”, which are a preprocessing step of a special C precompilation. This java edit the precompilated files and mix them, and the returns this post-edited file that have to be written in the bazel file structure.
The java program can’t run inside the bazel sandbox?
I tried installing the program under the bazel structure of directories, but the error persists
How bazel permit the java execution in it sandbox? and how this java program can write insithe files structure of bazel?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ctx.action.run this is how we execute the binary target. Can you elaborate your query with more details like what is error or problem seeing while doing the above.